# show modal dialog jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I'm trying to display a modal dialog pressed table cells, but does not work. Button works very well, but not in the table.
My code is as follows:

html

```
    <table class="clndr-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header-days">
            <td class="header-day">S</td>
            <td class="header-day">M</td>
            <td class="header-day">T</td>
            <td class="header-day">W</td>
            <td class="header-day">T</td>
            <td class="header-day">F</td>
            <td class="header-day">S</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="day past adjacent-month last-month calendar-day-2015-08-30">
                <div class="day-contents">30</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past adjacent-month last-month calendar-day-2015-08-31">
                <div class="day-contents">31</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-01">
                <div class="day-contents" href="#alert" id="alert">1</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-02">
                <div class="day-contents">2</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-03">
                <div class="day-contents">3</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-04">
                <div class="day-contents">4</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-05">
                <div class="day-contents">5</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-06">
                <div class="day-contents">6</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-07">
                <div class="day-contents">7</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-08">
                <div class="day-contents">8</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-09">
                <div class="day-contents">9</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-10">
                <div class="day-contents">10</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-11">
                <div class="day-contents">11</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-12">
                <div class="day-contents">12</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-13">
                <div class="day-contents">13</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-14">
                <div class="day-contents">14</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-15">
                <div class="day-contents">15</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-16">
                <div class="day-contents">16</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-17">
                <div class="day-contents">17</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-18">
                <div class="day-contents">18</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-19">
                <div class="day-contents">19</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-20">
                <div class="day-contents">20</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-21">
                <div class="day-contents">21</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-22">
                <div class="day-contents">22</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-23">
                <div class="day-contents">23</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-24">
                <div class="day-contents">24</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-25">
                <div class="day-contents">25</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day today calendar-day-2015-09-26">
                <div class="day-contents">26</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day calendar-day-2015-09-27">
                <div class="day-contents">27</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day calendar-day-2015-09-28">
                <div class="day-contents">28</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day calendar-day-2015-09-29">
                <div class="day-contents">29</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day calendar-day-2015-09-30">
                <div class="day-contents">30</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2015-10-01">
                <div class="day-contents">1</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2015-10-02">
                <div class="day-contents">2</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2015-10-03">
                <div class="day-contents">3</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

COPY TO CLIPBOARD    SELECT 
This table generates the days of the month in calendar form. I try to do is to show a modal dialog with the tasks for the selected day.
I'm trying to:

```
<td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-01">
    <div class="day-contents" href="#alert" id="alert">1</div>
</td>
```

But the dialog does not appear.

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      //alert
    $('a#alert').click(function(){
        modal({
            type  : 'alert',
            title : 'Alert',
            text  : "Simple Message!"
        });
    });
});
```

Can you give me any advice on how to display the dialog by pressing a table cell?
regards

Comment: what are you using for modal-dialog?

Comment: Hi Heberon, it would be great to know which tool you are using. in case you want to build you own modal this link is a great help and I have try it http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an anchor tag in your table. In jquery selector you should be using

```
$('div#alert').click(function(){})
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
      //alert
    $('div#alert').click(function(){
       alert('clicked');
        modal({
            type  : 'alert',
            title : 'Alert',
            text  : "Simple Message!"
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="clndr-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header-days">
            <td class="header-day">S</td>
            <td class="header-day">M</td>
            <td class="header-day">T</td>
            <td class="header-day">W</td>
            <td class="header-day">T</td>
            <td class="header-day">F</td>
            <td class="header-day">S</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="day past adjacent-month last-month calendar-day-2015-08-30">
                <div class="day-contents">30</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past adjacent-month last-month calendar-day-2015-08-31">
                <div class="day-contents">31</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-01">
                <div class="day-contents" href="#alert" id="alert">1</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-02">
                <div class="day-contents">2</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-03">
                <div class="day-contents">3</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-04">
                <div class="day-contents">4</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-05">
                <div class="day-contents">5</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-06">
                <div class="day-contents">6</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-07">
                <div class="day-contents">7</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-08">
                <div class="day-contents">8</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-09">
                <div class="day-contents">9</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-10">
                <div class="day-contents">10</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-11">
                <div class="day-contents">11</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-12">
                <div class="day-contents">12</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-13">
                <div class="day-contents">13</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-14">
                <div class="day-contents">14</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-15">
                <div class="day-contents">15</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-16">
                <div class="day-contents">16</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-17">
                <div class="day-contents">17</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-18">
                <div class="day-contents">18</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-19">
                <div class="day-contents">19</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-20">
                <div class="day-contents">20</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-21">
                <div class="day-contents">21</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-22">
                <div class="day-contents">22</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past event calendar-day-2015-09-23">
                <div class="day-contents">23</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-24">
                <div class="day-contents">24</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day past calendar-day-2015-09-25">
                <div class="day-contents">25</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day today calendar-day-2015-09-26">
                <div class="day-contents">26</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day calendar-day-2015-09-27">
                <div class="day-contents">27</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day calendar-day-2015-09-28">
                <div class="day-contents">28</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day calendar-day-2015-09-29">
                <div class="day-contents">29</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day calendar-day-2015-09-30">
                <div class="day-contents">30</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2015-10-01">
                <div class="day-contents">1</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2015-10-02">
                <div class="day-contents">2</div>
            </td>
            <td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2015-10-03">
                <div class="day-contents">3</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help
Adding the script
"<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"
calendar function does not work and does not show the current day.
The dialog is not displayed, only direct alert you added but the modal with styles does not run from the table.
The modal I'm using is as follows: https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.modal
Thank you for all your effort